# R highcharter() global thousand separator?

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

Is there a way to have my highcharter graph have a thousands separator on the y axis and the tooltip? Not sure if there are separate ways of doing this, or if there is a global option. The tooltip data point is formatted so there is a space where a comma should be. I've googled a bunch and just can't figure this out. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

code:

```
    hc <- jobs %>% hchart(
  'line', hcaes(x = new_time, y = employment), color = "#34657F") %>%
  hc_title(
    text = "Virginia", 
    align="left",
    style = list(fontFamily = "Montserrat")) %>%
  hc_subtitle(text= "Employment (in thousands) since March 2018 <br>",
    align="left",
    style = list(fontFamily = "Montserrat")) %>%
  hc_xAxis(title = list(enabled = FALSE)) %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(enabled = FALSE)) %>%
  hc_chart(style = list(fontFamily = "Open Sans")) 
hc
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The package author jbkunst provides [this answer here](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/69#issuecomment-216006952):

```
library(highcharter)
library(magrittr)

# set options
hcoptslang <- getOption("highcharter.lang")
hcoptslang$thousandsSep <- ","
options(highcharter.lang = hcoptslang)

# plot with commas
highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = round(rnorm(100)*10000))
```

[image]

Comment: After spending days trying to answer this question, finally found the answer. Thank you! How would I add a currency symbol in front of the number?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the global options (as mentioned in Rich Pauloo answer)

```
library(highcharter)
library(magrittr)

# set options
hcoptslang <- getOption("highcharter.lang")
hcoptslang$thousandsSep <- ","
options(highcharter.lang = hcoptslang)
```

and than set the axis labes as follows:

```
# plot with commas and axis
highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = round(rnorm(100)*10000))%>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "YourAxis"), #new part for axis labelling
           labels=list(format="{value:,f}")) #new part for axis separator
```

That will give you both, the tooltip and the axis:

[image: A screenshot from R showing that now axis and tooltip have separators]

Comment: I just found out that you can format the decimal places by adding `.#f` to `format ="{point.y: ,f .2f}"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use API functions for this and customize this tooltip as you like:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Example:

```
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "<b>{point.name}</b>:<br>",
             formatter = JS("function(){ return point.value * 100 + '%'; }"))
```

Here you can find an article that may also be helpful explaining how to work with Highcharts JavaScript syntax in R: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/working-with-highcharts-javascript-syntax-in-r/?fbclid=IwAR3RJo3gPURMhJCtcs5o8LqAzOhT8EN957Vijo2njd41YocX-oYv0LPijSA

Comment: thanks - I've seen this documentation. Do you have any more specific examples that could help me? I don't know JavaScript and am having a hard time understanding. Ideally, there would be some kind of option where the whole chart would have thousand separators. If not, then then thousand separators would suffice. I just can't figure out how to write the arguments in hc_tooltip for that to happen.